# My array is null when passed from the activity to a dialog

Tags: java, android, dialog, parameter-passing

I'm creating a dialog alert that will show a radio group, depending on the chosen option it will populate a list with the contents of one array or another.These arrays are populated on the main activity, so they are not null.  My problem is try to populate the list in the dialog, the arrays turn out to be empty, and I don't know how to pass the populated value there.

These are the lines that cause problems:

```
adapter = new populateListView(MainActivity.this, all_times_array, all_runtimes_array);
```

And this is the code for my dialog:

```
public void dialog_filter() {

  final String[] grpname = {
   "Today",
   "This Month",
   "This Year",
   "All time"
  };

  AlertDialog.Builder alt_bld = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

  //alt_bld.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
  alt_bld.setTitle("See reports from ...");
  alt_bld.setSingleChoiceItems(grpname, -1, new DialogInterface
   .OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
     time_filter = item;
     System.out.println(time_filter);
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
      grpname[item] + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


     switch (time_filter) {


      case 3:

       adapter = new populateListView(MainActivity.this, all_times_array, all_runtimes_array);
       bannertext = "Total seizures:" + " " + total_seizures;
       banner.setText(bannertext);
       list.setAdapter(adapter);

       break;

      case 0:
       adapter = new populateListView(MainActivity.this, today_times_array, today_runtimes_array);
       bannertext = "Today seizures:" + " " + today_seizures;
       banner.setText(bannertext);
       list.setAdapter(adapter);
       break;

      case 1:
       adapter = new populateListView(MainActivity.this, month_times_array, month_runtimes_array);
       bannertext = "Month seizures:" + " " + month_seizures;
       banner.setText(bannertext);
       list.setAdapter(adapter);
       break;
      case 2:
       adapter = new populateListView(MainActivity.this, year_times_array, year_runtimes_array);
       bannertext = "Year seizures:" + " " + year_seizures;
       banner.setText(bannertext);
       list.setAdapter(adapter);
       break;


     }
     dialog.dismiss();

    }
   });
  AlertDialog alert = alt_bld.create();
  alert.show();
```

These are the methods my pupulateListView class:

```
class populateListView extends ArrayAdapter <String>
```

{

```
    Context context;
    String [] times;
    String [] runtimes;



    populateListView(Context c,String [] tms, String [] rts)
    {
        super(c, seizure_list2,R.id.firstLine,tms);

        this.context=c;
        this.runtimes=rts;
        this.times = tms;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row = inflater.inflate(seizure_list2,parent,false);
        TextView runtime_text = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.secondLine);
        TextView time_text = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.firstLine);

        time_text.setText(times[position]);
        runtime_text.setText(runtimes[position]);
        return row;


    }
}
```

Comment: I checked all the similar questions and none seem to fit my case because.

Comment: Are you sure `all_times_array` and `all_runtimes_array` for example are not empty? Could you print the length of them before creating the adapter?

Comment: where you have initialized those arrays in your activity

Comment: Yes, they are empty but only in the dialog, when i print them in the main activity, they all contain data. They are initialized as a public , and then during oncreate they become populated.

Comment: You need to show us more code. What does `adapter` resolve to? What is `all_times_array` and how is it initialized? How do you check if your `all_runtimes_array` is not empty in this context? Also what is `populateListView` what library is that? It is not part of the normal android API.

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: You shouldn't populate your `List` in the `Dialog`, since the purpose of a Dialog is to get a user's choice. Instead, you should capture the value the user chosen in your `Dialog` and get it in your `MainActivity`, where you would populate your `List` based on the chosen value.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion!
Create a layout file with your radio group,and set this layout to your alert dialogue

```
 dialog.setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);
```

after that refer to your radioi group in layout

```
RadioGroup youradiogroup = (RadioGroup) dialog.findViewById(R.id.youradiogroupID);
```

and get the value of selected item in

```
youradiogroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group,
                                     int checkedId) {
            if (checkedId == R.id.first_radiobutton) {
                //do something}
            else  if (checkedId == R.id.second_radiobutton) {
                //do something else }
            }
    });
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: Good suggestion, but this is a Q&A site. Please answer the question in instead and then you can include your suggestion with it. The best thing to do is add your suggestion as a comment so that others will not skip over this question because it already has an answer. If you do want to help with code reviews then you can head over here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I thought it would help it because i faced the same problem in one of my projects. And thank you for your reply,now i have to delete the answer and add it as comment ?

Comment: That's normally the best way to do it, but since your answer is here already maybe leave this one but keep comments in mind for next time.

Comment: Thank you,i will !